# Standard pattern to redirect a submit form after checking the insert was successful, on Meteor with AutoForm & Iron Router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-autoform

I'm using Meteor with AutoForm & Iron Router.

I have an autoform for inserting a record, and I want to redirect to another page to view the record after a successful insert.  **What's the generally accepted way to do this?**

If I use the standard autoform insert like:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Articles" id="articleSubmit" type="insert"}}
```

I can't see how I can redirect?

If I use the 'method' type like this:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Articles" id="articleSubmit" type="method"}}
```

then I have to write an insert method which is not particularly DRY.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A form is a form, if you use the `type="method"` thats means you are using a `Meteor.method` for this, and the form will handle for you, the `Meteor.call`

Now if you want to do some `Router.go()`, you will need to write some JS code, you can use the hooks, wich come with the autoform package, like this for example

```
Articles.hooks({
  contactForm: {
    onSubmit: function (insertDoc, updateDoc, currentDoc) {
      if (someHandler(insertDoc)) {
        this.done();
        Articles.clean(doc); / you can do more logic here, cleaning the form.
        Router.go('thePath');
      } else {
        this.done(new Error("Submission failed"));
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

So you don't need a common `'submit #articleSubmit'` use the auto forms API better.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I decided to use the `onSuccess` hook as that is perfect for my use case.